# Why isn't "counting sort" a more widely used algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, sorting

I was graphing out letter frequency in some large academic documents. As part of this process, is was sorting letters from large clippings of those documents into alphabetical order. I was using `Python's` built in **sorted** function, and I started to wonder if I could make it faster. I then wrote the following function:

```
  def count_sort(l):
        items = {'a':0,'b':0,'c':0,'d':0,'e':0,'f':0,'g':0,'h':0,'i':0,'j':0,'k':0,'l':0,'m':
 0,'n':0,'o':0,'p':0,'q':0,'r':0,'s':0,'t':0,'u':0,'v':0,'w':0,'x':0,'y':0,'z'
:0}
        for item in l:
            items[item] += 1
        sort_l = []
        for key in items:
            sort_l += key*items[key]
        return sort_l
```

When testing this code versus `sorted` on a `10000` letter long string of text, it was almost `20X` faster.

With such a performance boost, why isn't this sorting algorithm in the standard `libs`?

Comment: This looks like a Counting sort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Comment: This is known as [Counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) and you should probably take something like an introduction to algorithms course or read an introductory book.

Comment: you might want to try `items = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)`

Comment: @kirelagin no need for the condescension

Comment: @wim Well, I didn’t want it to sound like condescension, sorry if it does. I just wanted to give a good advice.

Comment: I think the advice to take a course or read a book on algorithms was sound. If you want advice that's a different kind of sound, go check out the [Sound of Sorting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPRA0W1kECg).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have rediscovered the [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) algorithm.

To quote Wikipedia:

> For problem instances in which the maximum key value is significantly
> smaller than the number of items, counting sort can be highly
> space-efficient, as the only storage it uses other than its input and
> output arrays is the Count array which uses space O(k).

The counting sort algorithm becomes more and more efficient(relatively) the greater the difference is between the **total number of items** that being sorted, and the **number of unique items** being sorted.

You can see why this must be looking at your own code, or the [Wikipedia example code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#The_algorithm):

```
# calculate the histogram of key frequencies:
for x in input:
    count[key(x)] += 1

# calculate the starting index for each key:
total = 0
for i in range(k):   # i = 0, 1, ... k-1
    oldCount = count[i]
    count[i] = total
    total += oldCount

# copy to output array, preserving order of inputs with equal keys:
for x in input:
    output[count[key(x)]] = x
    count[key(x)] += 1

return output
```

You have 2 for loops in your function: the first to iterate over the letters you are sorting, and the second to iterate over the **items** dictionary. As I posited previously, this makes sense of the items dictionary is considerably smaller than the list you are sorting, but it quickly becomes very inefficient if the number of unique elements increases relative to the number of items being sorted.

Like @BrenBarn answered, this only when you know exactly what characters to expect and you're willing to ignore any other characters. While it seems like counting sort is highly efficient in the example you gave, the problem of sorting letters is hardly the most common sorting problem.

**Below I have fixed your function to print the letters by iterating through a list rather than iterating through the keys in a dictionary(as Python's dictionaries are not ordered)**

```
def count_sort(l):
    letters = [chr(i) for i in range(97, 122)]
    items = dict()
    for letter in letters:
        items[letter] = 0
    for item in l:
        items[item] += 1
    sort_l = list()
    for letter in letters:
        sort_l.extend(letter*items[letter])
    return sort_l
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments and answers above you can have rediscovered the counting sort but you haven't discovered the python [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) library:

```
from collections import Counter
def count_sort(l):
    items = Counter()
    for item in l:
        items[item] += 1
    sort_l = []
    for key in items.keys().sorted():
        sort_l += key*items[key]
    return sort_l
```

The major difference is that you will not get any entries for missing entries, you may also wish to change:

```
        sort_l += key*items[key]
```

to:

```
        sort_l.append((key, items[key]))
```

to return a sorted list of keys and counts.  Another good trick would be to return a `collections.OrderedDict` object.

Comment: 3 cheers for not reinventing the wheel, but your suggested edit for sort_l isn't valid. I fixed it.

Comment: @DavidGreydanus - I have corrected the append to return a list of tupples as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons.

One, your algorithm relies on knowing ahead of time what elements will exist in the list to be sorted.  If the list contained an uppercase character or a digit or anything else, your code would fail with an error.

The other reason is that your code relies on the order of the dictionary remaining the same.  Dictionaries are not ordered, so there is no guarantee that `for key in items` will iterate over the keys in alphabetical order.  Your "sorted" list might not wind up sorted at all.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answer, it is known as Counting Sort...

Other than the reasons / limitations they have mentioned,

Counting sort somehow use the **discrete** items as array index and count them

So if the item's domain is something like **double / floating point**, then
the implementation may be hard, at least maybe you have to use Map() to map the number into valid array index, and Map() itself is O(lg N), turns out the complexity is still O(N lg N)...

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in the counting sort and how it works with other sorting algorithms, you should check this analysis of the [Counting sort and Radix sort](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ads/Lects/lecture8.pdf) and the instances in which each of them are useful:

Many times counting sort can be useful as a sub-routine of a larger sorting (most notably [Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort))algorithm in instances where it would be impractical by itself.